# FDF to PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fdf

I was trying to create a pdf from an FDF file. I have created the FDF file succesfully.
But when i try to convert it into pdf i get some errors. Below is the part of my code. the test.pdf file open in a download box and when i try to open it gives error "couldn't open test.pdf because it is either not supported file type  or has been damaged"

```
if($fp=fopen($fdf_file,'w')){
            fwrite($fp,$fdf_data,strlen($fdf_data));
            echo $fdf_file,' written successfully.';
            header('Content-type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.pdf"');
            passssthru("pdftk test.pdf fill_form test.fdf output - ");
            exit;

        }else{
            die('U
```

Comment: Andromeda, Can you please share complete code if your problem solved FDF to PDF.
What is $fp and $fdf_data in your code? Please email me example code of the FDF to PDF which I can run easily and modify as per my requirement.
irfan.lateef@hotmail.com

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
if($fp=fopen($fdf_file,'w')){
        fwrite($fp,$fdf_data,strlen($fdf_data));
        //echo $fdf_file,' written successfully.';
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.pdf"');
        passssthru("pdftk test.pdf fill_form test.fdf output - ");
        exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `echo $fdf_file,' written successfully.';`

Comment: Have you tried passssthru("pdftk test.pdf fill_form test.fdf output test-out.pdf "); and verified that it works? Have you tried editing the PDF in a hex-editor to see what the data looks like?

Comment: No i haven't.... 

how do i test "passssthru("pdftk test.pdf fill_form test.fdf output test-out.pdf ".

Comment: just change output from stdout to a file in your example code.

Comment: I came to find that i haven't installed pdftk... i have got the source code ...but don't know how to use it.. what should i do?

Comment: depends on the operating system ubuntu/debian -> apt-get install pdftk

Comment: When i try "pdftk test.pdf fill_form test.fdf output test-out.pdf" in command line it shows " Input error . so not output created"

Comment: Yes..When i open test.fdf with adobe pro its asking me whether to save it to test.pdf and its working fine.

Comment: I'm afraid i can't do much without the files then... :(

Answer (score 0):

To further debug this, check the size of the downloaded file, and take a peek at it in an editor. I am guessing you have output before or after this code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to be making sure to directly reference where pdftk is installed, as such:

```
passthru('/usr/local/bin/pdftk /forms/test.pdf fill_form /forms/test.fdf output - ');
```

Also, you can add `>> output.pdf` at the end of the command to create a new pdf file.